# How to Right align a link inside an AppBar next to Tabs for Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Still relatively new to Material UI and ReactJS.

But I'm trying to have a set of tabs at the top of the page, but I also want a Logout link to the right side of the tabs.

Here's what I have

```
<AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="simple tabs example"
          style={{flex:1}}
        >
          <Tab label="Approvals"  />
          <Tab label="Members" />
        </Tabs>
        <a href="http://www.logout.com">Logout</a>
      </AppBar>
```

But the logout link isn't aligned to the right and is on a new line underneath the Tabs.

How would I go about having it sit at the end of the tabs?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can help you. Add  between  and Logout button.

```
<AppBar position="static">
     <Toolbar>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="simple tabs example"
          >
          <Tab label="Approvals"  />
          <Tab label="Members" />
        </Tabs>
        <Box flexGrow={1} />
        <Button>Logout</Button>
      </Toolbar>
 </AppBar>
```

Comment: This works thanks, is Box used here like a filler? What does flexGrow={1} do? and why wouldn't you have set it ss flexGrow="1"?

Comment: I can use box as filler by adding style to box "flex-grow:1".  flexGrow={1} adds style to box   "flex-grow:1". You can set it as flexGrow="1".